# Get a specific value from IList<IDictionary<string, string>> based on a string that needs to match the key of that value

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, dictionary

I have

```
IList<IDictionary<string,string>>
```

and Im trying to get a value of the list of dictionaries based on a string which needs to match the key.

For example if we have:

```
IList<IDictionary<string, string>> listOfDicts = new IList 
{
    new IDictionary<string, string>
    {
        {"key1", "value1"},
        {"key2", "value2"},
        {"key3", "value3"}
    }
};
```

How can I get "value2" based on a userInput string which is "key2" for this example, I need to match the key to the input and get the value?

Comment: Your "for example if we have" part won't compile - please provide a working starting point, at which point users will be able to help you with the rest of your task.

Comment: The question you just deleted wasn't off-topic, Maciek misunderstood the rules or what `recommendation` means. It was unclear though - sure, you need to test components and methods. Did you want to ask *how* to test your validation code in lifecycle methods? That's a good question

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Exactly. Im kinda new to unit test and these codes werent written by me so I was wondering if they could be tested and In that case, how should I proceed?

But maybe its better for me to write the question more clearly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you declared `List`, you have *several* dictionaries, e.g.

```
IList<IDictionary<string, string>> listOfDicts = 
  new List<IDictionary<string, string>>() {
    new Dictionary<string, string>() {
      { "key1", "value1" },
      { "key2", "value2" },
    },

    new Dictionary<string, string>() {
      { "key1", "OtherValue1" },
      { "key3", "OtherValue3" },
      { "key4", "OtherValue4" },
    },
  };
```

To obtain *all* values (`"value1"`, `"OtherValue1"`):

```
using System.Linq;

...

string key = "key1";

var values = listOfDicts
  .Where(dict => dict.ContainsKey(key))
  .Select(dict => dict[key])
  .ToArray(); // let's have an array of values
```

To obtain *first* value (`"value1"`) only:

```
string key = "key1";

string value = listOfDicts
  .FirstOrDefault(dict => dict.ContainsKey(key))
  ?[key] ?? "DefaultValue";
```

Comment: That should be `Contains`. `ContainsKey` is not a member of the `IDictionary` interface.

Comment: @jmcilhinney: `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` has `ContainsKey` method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.idictionary-2.containskey?view=net-8.0#system-collections-generic-idictionary-2-containskey(-0)

Comment: My apologies. I looked at `IDictionary` instead of the generic version.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to loop through the dictionaries and search for the key e.g.

```
string value = null;

foreach (var dict in listOfDicts)
{
    if(dict.TryGetValue("key2", out value))
    {
        break;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(value);
```

Comment: That will work with `List` and `Dictionary`, but the question is about `IList` and `IDictionary`.

Comment: The strategy will work with `IList` and `IDictionary`... the question doesn't provide code that compiles so I gave a quick example using the concrete types.

Comment: You gave an example with "some" concreate types. While it's unlikely, what about code that uses different concreate types? Regardless, the type of the objects is irrelevant if the code only knows the type of the interfaces, as a lot of testable code will.